# How can l extract characters withe same bounding box size?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, python, image-segmentation

l have a set of images which represent a sequence of characters. l'm wonderning whether OpenCV can segments and crop each character from the image with same bounding box size.

My numbers are not always neatly separated, the distance varies and it's small between characters most of time. So l'm looking for a technique to find a good bounding boxes for each character. Such that, all the bounding boxes for all characters have the same size.

Mainly l get bounding boxes small for a given character which divide it into two character. It divides 8 vertically into two part. Then l get two characters rather than the character 8.

[image: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/fhhfnj7WJAFgp7oPPbuIYOs9cmz8SkVHikoMFIEjnGzk--7Jllgbm-zLfHI7SXXm_nvVwC7YdEORbhs=w1364-h654]

Comment: can you post at least one of these images?

Comment: Unfortunately l can't. l'm new here, it's my first post, l need at least 3 points to be able to upload pictures. But l made a link for you . https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-QJnh0Uw96lRkV3UGZKcmFHelk

Comment: I'm outside this why l made for you a handwritten example. But my real examples are typed not handwritten

Comment: check out posts like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188104/character-recognition-ocr-algorithm